# TextView.setAllCaps() equivalent in API older than 14?

Tags: android, textview, uppercase

TextView.setAllCaps() started as of API 14. What is its equivalent for older APIs (e.g. 13 and lowers)?

I cannot find such method on lower APIs. Is maybe setTransformationMethod() responsible for this on older APIs? If yes, how should I use it? `TextView.setTransformationMethod(new TransformationMethod() {...` is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
textView.setText(textToBeSet.toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score 2):

What about oldskool `strtoupper()`?

Comment: we all laughed here how we forgot "the old school" things. upvote for bringing us back in dear time :).

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line is that `toUpperCase()` is the solution. I can't object that. If you prefer doing the `setAllCaps()` with `TransformationMethod`, take a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24025691/557179).