# Stop ToggleButton text Capitalization at API 10

Tags: android, android-tabs, android-togglebutton

I want to stop my ToggleButton's text from being capitalized at API 10.

I know I can use `setAllCap(false)` to stop the Cap lock of Toggle Button, but how can I do the same at API level 10, since  `setAllCap(false)` is only supported at API level 14, which is the Ice cream sandwich.

ps. In case someone wondering why am I doing this. (I know I am suppose to ask only one question, but this may help someone else with other problems)

I am trying to mimic tabs inside fragment by using a `TableLayout` with first row as toggle buttons, and changes the second row upon toggle those buttons. (FragmentTabHost is just problematic at the moment I think and is way too complicated for my use case). Everything works except the button text is always in upper case.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `ToggleButton.setTextOn()` and `ToggleButton.setTextOff()` and supply your own string. From what I can see from the implementation of `ToggleButton`, it does not auto capitalize strings set this way.

Comment: Hi @idunnololz I know it doesn't make sence to force user to use capitalised text but I tried setting onText offText, Text and even setTextKeepStates. Non of them works, always capital letter. Perhaps it is a drawback of the API 21, which forces the capitalization unless otherwise specified by setAllCap(false). I am using a Android which is on API 21 btw. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are using latest support library. You can take [AllCapsTransformationMethodCompat.java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24025784/557179) and apply setAllCaps(false) like this:

`AllCapsTransformationMethodCompat.setAllCaps(textViewInstance, true);` - to capitalize all

`AllCapsTransformationMethodCompat.setAllCaps(textViewInstance, text, false);` - to preserve original text

In the 21.0+ support library there is exactly same backport of this `MethodTransformation`

Comment: Hi Nikola, thank you very much for your answer. This is what I am using in my Gradle build at the moment : 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3' I reckon this can be a good solution and will get back to you if it turns out good !